# An example of covergence to an exponential distribution, the role of continuity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, examples-counterexamples

I got a probability problem I can solve, but my solution does not use an assumption which is given in the formulation of the problem. I am afraid that this is might be a sign that my solution is incorrect. Could you please take a look and let me know whether the assumption is indeed needed.

$X_1, X_2,...$ are i.i.d. random variables, $X_1$ has a continuous pdf $f(x)$ such that $\lambda = \lim_{0 \leftarrow x}f(x)>0$ and $f(x)>0$ $\forall x \in (0, \infty)$, $Z_n=n* \min(X_1,...,X_n)$, show that $Z_n \rightarrow Z$ in distribution and $Z$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$. My concern that I can show it without using the continuity of $f$.

We consider $x>0$, because for $x \le 0$ $P(Z_n>x)=1$.

$P(Z_n>x)=P(n* \min(X_1,...,X_n)>x)=P(X_1>\frac{x}{n})^n=(1-F_{X_1}(\frac{x}{n}))^n=(1-\int_0^{\frac{x}{n}}f(t)dt)^n$

I show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(Z_n>x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ $\forall x>0$.

I change value of $f$ just at point $0$, I say $f(0)=\lambda$. The changed $f$ is still pdf for $X_1$, and the changed pdf is right continuous, i.e. $\lim_{0 \leftarrow x}f(x)=\lambda=f(0)$.

Then $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta$ such that $\forall$ $0<t<\delta$ $|\lambda - f(t)|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda - \epsilon < f(t) < \lambda + \epsilon$. I find $n_0$ such that $\frac{x}{n_0}<\delta$, then $\forall n>n_0$:

$\int_{0}^{x/n}(\lambda - \epsilon)dt < \int_{0}^{x/n}f(t)dt<\int_{0}^{x/n}(\lambda + \epsilon)dt$.

Thus:

$\frac{(\lambda - \epsilon)x}{n}<F(\frac{x}{n})<\frac{(\lambda + \epsilon)x}{n}$,

and

($1-\frac{(\lambda - \epsilon)x}{n})^n>(1-F(\frac{x}{n}))^n>(1-\frac{(\lambda + \epsilon)x}{n})^n$.

It follows that:

$e^{-(\lambda - \epsilon)x} \ge \lim_{n \to \infty}P(Z_n>x) \ge e^{-(\lambda +\epsilon)x}$.

Because $\epsilon$ can be as close to $0$ as we wish, $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(Z_n>x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ and $Z$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$.

As you see I nowhere use the continuity of $f$, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Assuming [Riemann integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability), how do you justify the existence of integrals like
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{x/n}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,?
$$

Comment: I justify it by the fact that $f$ is a pdf $\Rightarrow$ can be integrated on any interval even if $f$ is discontinuous at a finite number of points, so I do not need continuity of $f$ to talk about its integral.

Comment: @SergeyZykov, ...but that is all you need! Why do you think the question requires anything more?

Comment: well, probably I am a bit too captious, but it seems that one does not need to mention in the question the fact that $f$ is continuous, because if $f$ is discontinuous (at a finite number of points of course), then the answer to the question does not change.

Comment: @SergeyZykov, I see. How do you guarantee that the bound $\lambda - \epsilon < f(t) < \lambda + \epsilon$ holds for all $0<t< x/n_0<\delta$ without strict continuity?

Comment: I use the fact that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, continuity at other points is not needed for the condition you mentioned above to be true. The continuity at $x=0$ is artificially constructed by me, specifically I say that $f(0)=\lambda$ and observe that $\lim_{x \leftarrow o}f(x)=\lambda$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ $\forall x$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$

Comment: @SergeyZykov, Thanks for the clarification. Apologies for not being clear; I wanted to know how much weaker you require $f$ to be. Not continuity "almost everywhere", it seems: in that case countably many discontinuities in a neighbourhood of $0$ might be a problem. I suppose I cannot see why you need right-continuity at $0$ and, i suspect, that

Comment: @SergeyZykov, ...the existence of a right-limit in a neighbourhood of $0$ is sufficient.